# Notepad++ counter part of editing in multiple lines in vim

Tags: vim, editor, vi

I want to select multiple lines in vim and whatever I type should be written on those lines.

It is easy to do in Notepad++ using `shift-alt` to select the cursor points and start typing.

For eg.

```
  17  #define       M_SPI_BASE              48098000
  18  #define       SPI2_BASE               4809A000
  19  #define       SPI3_BASE               0x480B8000
  20  #define       SPI4_BASE               0x480BA000
```

As in line numbers 19 and 20, I want to add `0x` in front of the addresses 48098000 & 4809A000 in line 17 & 18 to get 0x48098000 & 0x4809A000 respectively.

I want to select my cursor at two different points i.e., before 48098000 & 4809A000 and type `0x`.

How do I do it in vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [Visual Blockmode](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/selecting-columns-with-visual-block-mode/)

With your cursor before `48098000` you can use following sequence

<kbd>ctrl+v</kbd>`jI0x`<kbd>Esc</kbd>

What might trip you up is that the changes to other rows are only made after leaving visual blockmode, not while typing them.

Breakdown:

- <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd>   Start Visual mode Blockwise
- `j`       Select downwards
- `I` Start insert
- `0x` Add text
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> Leave Visual mode. Vim will add the text you've typed to the selection.

Comment: Much of the little vim-fu I have mastered to date comes from those little nuggets of gold. The book is an eye opener. Very much recommend it.

Comment: That's great! Is there a way to post a question on vim to you directly?

Comment: @SJMP - If it's possibly remotely interesting to others, feel free to post another question here on SO and no doubt it will get picked up in no time. I'm flabbergasted I even got a chance to answer this one :)